# How do I make property accessors all on one line, including closing braces, in Visual Studio 2017, both when authoring and refactoring?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, accessor

The Encapsulate Field refactoring produces very spread out accessors:

```
    private int steps= 6;

    public int Steps
    {
        get
        {
            return steps;
        }

        set
        {
            steps= value;
        }
    }
```

I found how I could change the first brace by going to:
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Formatting -> New Lines -> New Line Options for braces and unchecking:
"Place open brace in a new line for property, indexer, and event accessors"

Now I get this:

```
private int steps= 6;

public int Steps
{
    get{
        return steps;
    }

    set{
        steps= value;
    }
}
```

But I want to go a step further and end up with this:

```
private int steps= 6;

public int Steps
{
    get { return steps; }
    set { steps= value; }
}
```

How do I convince Visual Studio that it should be even more compact?

EDIT: The propfull snippet is great (thanks @popsiporkkanaa), but I can't use that to automatically refactor existing private members to properties.

Comment: Why not use auto-properties anyway and have `public int Steps { get; set; } = 6;`? Doesn't get much more compact than that (and VS should offer a "refactor to auto property" option, at least per property).

Comment: did you tried formatting > wrapping option?

Comment: I'm working in Unity3D, which requires a bunch of attributes on the private variable, so I can't use auto properties. I'm not familiar enough with it to explain why, but I understand it as a constraint that must be followed.

Comment: @Vinit Yes, I tried that, but those settings change everything in the project, not just the property accessors.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio there is a snippet of "propfull", which will offer you this:

```
   public int MyProperty
   {
        get { return myVar; }
        set { myVar = value; }
   }
```

Comment: This is a pretty good tool, and it's what I've adopted when I create new properties, but I can't use it to refactor existing private members that should be properties. :(

Answer (score 1):

For compact accessors, check out Code Style > General > Expression preferences > Use expression body for accessors = "When possible" or "When on single line".

Then when you refactor with "Encapsulate field" it will return

```
public int Steps { get => steps; set => steps = value; }
```